# How to get Amazon s3 PHP SDK working?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to set up s3 for the first time and trying to run the sample file that comes with the PHP sdk that creates a bucket and attempts to upload some demo files to it. But this is the error I am getting:

```
The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

I read on another question on SO that this is because Amazon determines a valid request by comparing the times between the server and the client, that the 2 must be within a 15 min span of one another.

Now here is the problem. My laptop's time is `12:30AM June 8, 2012` at the moment. On my server I created a file called servertime.php and placed this code in that file:

```
<?php
   print strftime('%c');
?>
```

and the output is:

```
Fri Jun 8 00:31:22 2012
```

It looks like the day is correct but I don't know what to make of `00:31:22`. In any case, how is it possible to always make sure the time between the client and server is within a 15 minute window of one another. What if I have a user in China who wishes to upload a file on my site which uses s3 for the cdn. Then the time difference would be over a day. How can I make sure all my user's times are within 15 minutes of my server time? What if the user is in the U.S. but the time on their machine is misconfigured.

Basically how to get s3 bucket creation and upload to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your EC2 instance and your S3 bucket inside the same region and make sure your server 
has the correct time:

**Debian/Ubuntu**

```
// install ntp
apt-get install ntp ntpdate
```

**CentOS/Fedora**

```
// install ntp
yum install ntp

// turn on service
chkconfig ntpd on

// synchronize system clock with 0.pool.ntp.org server
ntpdate pool.ntp.org

// start ntp
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

That should fix your problems.

Comment: wow that worked automagically, thanks! Just one question before I pick this is the answer. Now that "ntp ntpdate" is installed on my server will this ensure that all my app's users no matter from what part of the world they are at and no matter whether the times on their computers are misconfigured. Will all users be able to upload files to my s3 bucket or will some of them encounter the time error?

Comment: Yes, any user will be abled to upload files, because they'll be first transfered to your server and then put into the S3 bucket.